# Looking for a Java grammar in lex/yacc format

Tags: java, yacc, lex

Does anyone know an online repository for lex/yacc format grammars? I'm looking for a Java grammar to make a quicky sourcecode converter.

Thank you!

edit: I'm preferably looking for lex/yacc because I want to use fslex/fsyacc with as little grammar rewriting as possible.

Comment: Seems like you could just reuse a C parser and make "class" and "interface" work like "struct" and "import" work like "#include".

Comment: That might be the fastest option actually. I should have thought of that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org) has a Java grammar.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly lex/yacc format but the JavaCC project hosts a couple grammars [here](https://javacc.dev.java.net/servlets/ProjectDocumentList?folderID=110).

Answer (score 0):

[SableCC](http://sablecc.org/) is also a possible candidate. It works great.